# How to disable function name convention check?

Tags: android-studio, lint

Android Studio 3 underlines my test name. As a result it's harder to read and see spell check. How to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also go to **Settings -> Inspections -> Naming conventions -> Function naming convention** and uncheck checkbox.

[image]
By the way, you can also change a pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Usually what you can do is put your cursor there on the function name, hit `Alt + Enter` and then you'll get a bunch of options. One of which you can select (using the arrows) and then go to `Edit Settings` and then you can deactivate it for your project.